# Storing volley request for using it afterwards

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a requirement where in the request/response  flow is as following:-

Web request A is made, get a security question , answer is sent to server, server responds as success, then again web request A is made.

I am using volley for making all my web service calls. My question is there a way in which we can save the Request A and call it again when the security question is a success.

Comment: Yes, you can save any `Request` object. It's only when you add to the queue is it executed

Comment: could you tell me how can I save the request object and then add it whenever I need it

Comment: How are you currently making a request? I assume you have a `new StringRequest` made? Then you add to the queue?